# No ajax working with simple form client side validations in rails

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form, client-side-validation

I'm experiencing an issue where validations do not happen live with the form, they only show up after the user hits submit. I'm using the `simple_form` gem with `client_side_validations` and `client_side_validations-simple_form`. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Gemfile

```
gem 'simple_form', '~>2.0.4'
gem 'client_side_validations'
gem 'client_side_validations-simple_form', '~>2.0.1'
```

Form intro

`<%= simple_form_for @position, validate: true do |f| %>`

position.rb

`validates :cost_basis, presence: true`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work with [this script](https://gist.github.com/ddarren/2705324#file_client_side_validations_twitter_boostrap_simple_form.js).